# Deserializing a multiple different key/value JSon Arrays/strings into a collection of the same class in C#

Tags: c#, json

I've got incoming json arrays that I need to de-serialize into a class.  The class is basically a two property class but the incoming json arrays may have different Key names but they will always be in a keyname/value pair.

Is there a way to do this without having to create a different class for each variation?
My class:

```
 public class MyGenericClass
    {
        public string ColumnName { get; set; }

        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

Two possible json strings that I want to de-serialize into the above class:

```
[
    {
        "Test": "BTO"
    },
    {
        "Test": "Test I"
    },
    {
        "Test": "Test II"
    },
    {
        "Test": "Regi"
    },
    {
        "Test": "ISV"
    },
    {
        "Test": "Bill"
    }
]
```

Example 2:

```
[
    {
        "State": "Fried"
    },
    {
        "State": "Shredded"
    },
    {
        "State": "Licked"
    },
    {
        "State": "Rated"
    },
    {
        "State": "Smooth"
    },
    {
        "State": "WY"
    }
]
```

Comment: The simple and naive solution is to first create a model that matches your JSON, something like `Dictionary<string, string>[]`, then deserialize the json into that, then manually transform that dictionary into instances of MyGenericClass.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, string>[]` is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, the solution includes deserializing to `Dictionary<string, string>[]` and then transforming that into `MyGenericClass`.

```cs
// 'data' is a string variable with the raw JSON data
Dictionary<string, string>[] dicts = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>[]>(data);
IEnumerable<MyGenericClass> result = dicts
    .Select(dict => dict.Single()) // select the first key-value pair of each dictionary
    .Select(kvp => new MyGenericClass { ColumnName = kvp.Key, Value = kvp.Value }); // create a new 'MyGenericClass' from each key-value pair
// print out the results
foreach (MyGenericClass obj in result) {
    Console.WriteLine($"ColumnName = {obj.ColumnName}, Value = {obj.Value}");   
}
```